# Eliminar jugadores en un listado con Array

Tags: javascript, html, array, formularios

estoy intentando crear un formulario que añada jugadores a una lista con su id, DNI, nombre, apellidos, fecha de nacimiento y localidad y los muestre, además tiene que tener otro formulario que, añadiendo o la id o el DNI del jugador, borre sus datos.
Cuento con el siguiente código JS:

```
function Jugador(id, dni, name, apellidos, fecha, localidad, dinero) {
    this.id = id;
    this.dni = dni;
    this.name = name;
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
    this.fecha = fecha;
    this.localidad = localidad;
}

var jugadores = [];

function obtenerDNI() {  // Obtengo el DNI del input

    var obtenerD = document.getElementById("dni").value;
    return obtenerD;

}

function obtenerNombre() {  // Obtengo el nombre del input

    var obtenerN = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    return obtenerN;

}

function obtenerApellidos() {  // Obtengo los apellidos del input

    var obtenerA = document.getElementById("apellidos").value;
    return obtenerA;

}

function obtenerFecha() { // Obtengo la edad del input

    var obtenerF = document.getElementById("fecha").value;
    obtenerF = parseInt(obtenerF);

    return obtenerF;
}

function obtenerLocalidad() {  // Obtengo la localidad del input

    var obtenerL = document.getElementById("localidad").value;
    return obtenerL;

}

function crearJugador() {

    var jug = new Jugador(jugadores.length + 1, obtenerDNI(), obtenerNombre(), obtenerApellidos(),
        obtenerFecha(), obtenerLocalidad(), 0);
    jugadores.push(jug);
    mostrarListado();
}

function mostrarListado() {
    var lista = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < jugadores.length; i++) {
        lista += 'Numero de socio: ' + jugadores[i].id +
            ' DNI: ' + jugadores[i].dni +
            ' nombre: ' + jugadores[i].name +
            ' apellidos: ' + jugadores[i].apellidos +
            ' fecha de nacimiento: ' + jugadores[i].fecha +
            ' localidad: ' + jugadores[i].localidad +
            '\n';
    }
    document.getElementById('listado').innerText = lista;
}
```

Y este es su código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Formulario Jugadores</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jugador.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <style>
        body {

            background-color: #111111;
        }

        h1,
        h2,
        div {

            color: white;
        }
    </style>
    <form>
        <h2>Formulario inserción usuarios</h2>
        <input type="text" id="dni" placeholder="DNI" />
        </br></br>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" placeHolder="Nombre" />
        </br></br>
        <input type="text" id="apellidos" placeholder="apellidos" />
        </br></br>
        <input type="text" id="fecha" placeholder="Fecha de nacimiento" />
        </br></br>
        <input type="text" id="localidad" placeholder="Localidad" />
        </br></br>
        <input type="button" onClick="crearJugador();" value="Enviar mis datos!" />

    </form>

    <form>
        <h2>Eliminar usuarios</h2>
        <input type="number" id="jugadorid" placeHolder="id" />
        <input type="text" id="dni" placeHolder="dni" />
    </form>

    <div id="listado"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Pero por más código que pruebo (probé distintas formas de borrar elementos de un array, como slice y demás), no logro crear una función que me elimine a los jugadores al introducir su DNI o su ID.
¿Alguien tiene una solución a esto o una propuesta de mejora de código?
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes recorrer tu array de jugadores, luego en cada objeto de clase buscar el id del jugador a eliminar, de la siguiente manera:

```
function eliminar(id) {
     for (var i =0; i < jugadores.length; i++) {
           if (jugadores[i].id === id) {
             jugadores.splice(i,1);
           break;
       }
     }
     console.log('el for', jugadores);
 }
```